# mysql_stmt_fetch_column(), how to use non-zero offset

Tags: c++, mysql

Has anyone successfully used mysql_stmt_fetch_column() with offset > 0?

The non-zero offset appears to have no effect in the following:

```
if (length[i] == 0) break;
if (StrBufLen == 0)
{
    int cnt = StrBlobLen, retval;
    (**results).elt[row * cols + i] = LVStr((char*) str[i].c_str(), min<int>(length[i], StrBlobLen));
    while (cnt < length[i])
    {
        if ((retval = mysql_stmt_fetch_column(api.my.stmt, api.my.bind, i, cnt)) != 0)
            {errnum = retval; errstr = mysql_error(api.my.con); return -1;}
        LV_str_cat((**results).elt[row * cols + i], (char*) str[i].c_str(), min<int>(length[i] - cnt, StrBlobLen));
        cnt += StrBlobLen;
    }
}
```

I looked at the source for libmysql.cc and found these lines (2818):

```
  char *start = value + param->offset;
  char *end = value + length;
```

I suspect it should be:

```
  char *start = value + param->offset;
  char *end = start + length;
```

My offset **is** the length of the buffer, so the function would appear to copy zero bytes on the second call.

Comment: What's not working here? What's an example of the query you're executing? Does the query work in the `mysql` shell or client?

Comment: `min<int>` suggests this is C++.

Comment: Yes, this is C++.  Yes, the C API works just fine if I allocate a large enough buffer.  But I really want to know if anyone has used mysql_stmt_fetch_column() with non-zero _offset_  I looked at the source and think I've identified a bug.